# How to get all contacts through the Acumatica REST API

Tags: acumatica

I know the normal way to get all records of an entity is 
http://localhost/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/17.200.001/"entity"
However, when I use this method to return the Contact entity I receive an error.

"exceptionMessage":  Optimization cannot be performed.The following fields cause the error:
AddressValidated: View AddressCurrent has BQL delegate

ExceptionType: PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.CannotOptimizeException

I have tried adding parameters such as filtering by last modified date this still did not work. I know that you can get a single contact by providing the ID but this is not what I want. I want to return a list.

Comment: Does it work if you provide a Select parameter and just pick a few fields?

Comment: It is as Rochelle said, you need to exclude returned fields coming from AddressCurrent delegate. BQL Delegates can execute custom logic beyond simple SQL querying that severely degrade performance so the API forces single record retrieval on these.

Comment: Ok it works as long as I exclude address validation. What if the URL gets too long?